# C# - Parse Error for Math Formula with Jace.NET

Tags: c#

I have a C# app that performs some calculations. One of my calculations looks like this:

```
var equation = "((5 * 0.5)+(2x * 0.25)+(3x * 0.2)) * y";
```

I then attempt to run this equation through the Jace.NET calculation engine using the following:

```
Dictionary<string, double> variables = new Dictionary<string, double>();
variables.Add("x", 2);
variables.Add("y", 5.25);

var engine = new CalculationEngine();
var result = engine.Calculate(equation, variables);
System.WriteLine(result);
```

When the code gets to the `engine.Calculate` line, I get an error that says:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Jace.ParseException' occurred in Jace.dll
"The syntax of the provided formula is not valid."
```

Perhaps I'm too close to the code. I do not see what's wrong with my equation though. It looks correct to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try writing `2x` as `2*x`

Comment: In your case must be the missing * operator, but I've a similar problem with floating point literals... `Jace.ParseException: Invalid token "." detected at position 86` when I use 0.2 like in your code...